# How to make a class immutable when its referencing a mutable object?

Tags: java, immutability

Let's say I have a class in java called *Employee* that looks something like this

```
public class Employee {
    private String empName;
    private int empId;

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this object in an immutable class let's say a company in the following format. and the condition is that I cannot modify

```
public final class Company {
    final String companyName;
    final Employee employee;

    public Company(String companyName, Employee employee) { 
        this.companyName = companyName; 
        this.employee = employee; 
    } 
    public String getCompanyName() { 
        return companyName; 
    } 
    public Employee getEmployee() { 
        return employee; 
    }
}
```

So my question is, is this a valid way to make Company class immutable when I am referencing an inside object that can be modified?

Comment: I think to do that, in my opinion, is to mage getEmployee return always a new Employee with the employee data. You can render the employee object inside your company immutable.

Comment: Think the best solution would be to add a "deepClone" interface which would return a deep copy of the Employee object. Calling it like this.employee = employee.deepClone();

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want Company to have a *snapshot* of the originally-passed-in Employee -- even if that means it doesn't match the current state of the Employee after that?

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in this article https://www.journaldev.com/129/how-to-create-immutable-class-in-java do a deep cloning of Employee object in your constructor of final class. This way you will won’t use the object reference.

Answer (score 1):

2 things that came to my mind:

1. Add a `ReadOnlyEmployee` Interface for your `Employee` which only exposes the getters. Then you would have to change the return type of `getEmployee()` to `ReadOnlyEmployee`.  The advantage of this solution is that it's clear and explicit for the user. The problem is that the getter returns another type than the constructor accepts which may be confusing.
2. Add a proxy class that extends the `Employee` class that throws an `IllegalAccessException` or similar on setter calls. The advantage is that you do not have to introduce new Interfaces or change the methods of `Company`. The disadvantage is the possible runtime Exceptions.

Comment: Another advantage of the proxy class is you don't have to clone anything, just wrap Employee. This however only works when the attributes of Employee are primitives. If an Employee can hold a Car instance, you also need to wrap `getCar()` to make the returned Car object immutable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you release a reference to an employee instance, thus the caller may modify the object.

1. You return a link to a copy of the employee and stop worrying about what will happen next. You protected the underlying instance. The caller can do whatever they want with a copy, while your field remains consistent and effectively unchanged (in fact, it's changeable, of course).

   ```
   public class Employee {
       public Employee(Employee o) {
           // copy evething you need from o
       }
   }

   public final class Company {
       public Employee getEmployee() { 
           return new Employee(employee); 
       }
   }
   ```

   Problems here? The caller is altering the employee's data and can't figure out why nothing has been changed within the company.
2. You return a reference to a `Company`'s inner subclass of `Employee`. In this class, you override setters and other methods that change the state. The caller, for instance, might be getting an `UnsupportedOperationException` when they call such modifying methods on a retrieved `Employee`.

   ```
   public final class Company {
       private final CompanyEmployee companyEmployee;

       public Company(String companyName, Employee employee) { 
           this.companyName = companyName; 
           companyEmployee = new CompanyEmploye(employee); 
       }

       private static class CompanyEmployee extends Employee {
           public Employee(Employee o) {
               super(o);
           }

           public void setEmpName(String empName) {
               throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
           }
           public void setEmpId(int empId) {       
               throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
           }
       }

       public Employee getEmployee() { 
           return companyEmployee;
       }
   }
   ```

   Problems here? Inheritance is used to control access.
3. Otherwise, an immutable class that is made of mutable components isn't *that* immutable.

> Is this a valid way to make `Company` class immutable when I am referencing an inside object that can be modified?

No. From my understanding, any component obtained from an instance of an immutable class shouldn't be alterable. No matter at what level a request to change may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no. Adding `final` makes the reference immutable: you cannot assign a different `Employee` object. `this.employee = ...` is impossible.

However, finality isn't contagious the way constness is in C++. It's still possible to call `getEmployee().setEmpName(...)` or `getEmployee().setEmpId(...)` and modify the employee object. You can't replace it with a new one but you can modify the object that's there.

If you want to make `Company` completely immutable then you need to make defensive copies of the `Employee` object in two places. One, you need to copy the object passed in the constructor. Two, you need to return a copy from `getEmployee()` to prevent the internal object from being exposed.

```
public final class Company {
    final String companyName;
    final Employee employee;

    public Company(String companyName, Employee employee) { 
        this.companyName = companyName; 
        this.employee = new Employee(employee);     // 1
    } 
    public String getCompanyName() { 
        return companyName; 
    } 
    public Employee getEmployee() { 
        return new Employee(employee);              // 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was asked this question in an interview few days ago, it was quiet a tricky one so I thought to post it in forum.